# Nginx gzip filter not work with my custom handler

Tags: module, nginx, gzip, handler

I wrote a very simple nginx handler,just output some text (size 100B to 10KB).

the code works properly with nginx( ver 1.0.6)

but I found gzip filter can not work with the handler .

when I turn gzip on in nginx.conf (under http section), the gzip works file with static html files.

but, the handler's response is not compressed with gzip.

after a lot of search job, I still can not find the answer.

any comments ? thanks a lot. :-)

```
//my code :
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_test_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r){

    ngx_chain_t out;
    ngx_buf_t *b;

    b = ngx_pcalloc(r->pool, sizeof(ngx_buf_t));

    ......
    //writing text to buffer
    ......
    r->headers_out.status = NGX_HTTP_OK;
    r->headers_out.content_length_n = len;
    r->headers_out.content_type.len = sizeof("text/html")-1;
    r->headers_out.content_type.data = (u_char *) "text/html";

    out.buf = b;
    out.next = NULL;
    return ngx_http_output_filter(r, &out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too late, I had the same problem with my filter module.

The problem is related to the fact that you change the response Content-type. Gzip checks the Content-Type on content_type_len and content_type_lowcase to decide if the response must be Gziped. This code should work :

```
r->headers_out.content_type_len = strlen("text/html");
r->headers_out.content_type.len = strlen("text/html");
r->headers_out.content_type.data = (u_char *) "text/html";
r->headers_out.content_type_lowcase = NULL;
```

To understand why this code work, you have to consider that Gzip filter calls at first the method ngx_http_test_content_type to enable gzip on the response. You can see the source here : http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/http/ngx_http_core_module.c#L1659

Answer (score 0):

Firstly where is your call to `ngx_http_send_header(r);` ?

Are you initialising the members of  `ngx_buf_t *b` ?

Is your content encoding for the request set ?

Does your handler produce an error ? If so no filters will be called ?

Other constraints that need to be meet to ensure the gzip filter runs (rather than being bypassed) when called by your handler include

- Gzip must be enabled in the nginx configuration file see [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule)
- The sent header status should be either NGX_HTTP_OK, NGX_HTTP_FORBIDDEN or NGX_HTTP_NOT_FOUND
- The content encoding should be set (the ngx_table_elt_t* must exist and the value in should be have a non zero length
- The content_length_n should be valid (not -1) and should be greater than or equal to the gzip_min_length value specified in the configuration file
- ngx_http_test_content_type needs to return non null e.g, a valid context type
- The request needs to have a header and body

See [here](http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#filters) for more information regarding Nginx Module, Fillter and Handler developmennt.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer seems... inaccurate.

The code that checks this is located at or around line 250 of `src/http/modules/ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.c` and reads:

```
if (!conf->enable
    || (r->headers_out.status != NGX_HTTP_OK
        && r->headers_out.status != NGX_HTTP_FORBIDDEN
        && r->headers_out.status != 207
        && r->headers_out.status != NGX_HTTP_NOT_FOUND)
    || (r->headers_out.content_encoding
        && r->headers_out.content_encoding->value.len)
    || (r->headers_out.content_length_n != -1
        && r->headers_out.content_length_n < conf->min_length)
    || ngx_http_test_content_type(r, &conf->types) == NULL
    || r->header_only)
{
    return ngx_http_next_header_filter(r); <-- this is the line you want to breakpoint!
}
```

If I'm reading correctly, the conditions are:

- HTTP status must be 200, 403 or 404.
- content_encoding must *not* be set (which makes sense: gzipping sets the content encoding to "gzip")
- content_length_n, if set, must be greater than the minimum length (default 20). Not setting a content length is acceptable.
- content_type must be in the valid list. By default, only "text/html" is accepted, but other types can be set with the `gzip_types` config option. If the list includes "*", any content type, including none at all, is OK.
- There must be some body to compress

As of version 1.7.10, the `return` above is on line 257. Setting "daemon off", running under gdb and `b ngx_http_gzip_filter_module.c:257` will allow you to see precisely when and how the checks are failing. (You should probably compile from source if you're trying this...)